# Using parseFloat Sanitize or other Methods to clean variable output value issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, html

Am retrieving a distance using distance calculator script using Google Maps etc...

Then calculating a fare cost based on that distance, but the output from that script displays dynamically from Google as x,y miles in the distance field
using `document.getElementById("distance_road").value = distance1;`
and `distance1 = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;`
In the 'cost' field data accepted and entered in this format (00.00) so here the the output is resulting in a `$NAN` when trying to run the calculation.

Here is the cost script:

```
 function calculatefare() { /* variable declarations*/
   var subTotal=0.00;
   var pricePerFifthMile=0.54;
   var dropOffCharge=2.60;
   var overTwoPassengerCharge=0.50;
   var tripMilage=Number(document.getElementById("distance_road").value); 
   var passengers=Number(document.getElementById("passengers").value);
   /* if there are over 2 riders, each additional passenger pays $2 if (passengers>2)*/ { subTotal=overTwoPassengerCharge*(passengers-3+1); } 
   /* calculate the price based on miles in*/
   subTotal+=parseInt(tripMilage*5)*pricePerFifthMile; subTotal+=dropOffCharge; /* prints the price to the div. toFixed adds cents to integer calculations */
   document.getElementById('price').innerHTML=" $"+subTotal.toFixed(2);
 }
 // JavaScript Document
```

Is there any way to make this script accepts that format(read it) (xx,x miles)
or let say to clean this output to be xx.x  which means removing the ',' and 'miles'.
I tried : 
`sanitizedDistance = parseFloat(distance1.replace(",","."));`

Comment: One simple-ish way is to put validation on the filed with the miles and require only a number to be entered. Add the world "miles" after the box for the number, so the user doesn't try to enter it. There are many validation libraries available that can do that for you like Parsley. Once you ensure the input is valid, then proceed with the calculations.

Comment: The `sanitizedDistance` you tried is supposed to work... If you do not still use the [`number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) which is returning the `NaN`.

Comment: @vlaz: OP is getting the value from a distance calculator which I suppose to be [this one](https://www.distancecalculator.net/)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette ah, right, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to redefine the variable distance1, before getting outputed and called in the form. so the output will be parsed to define the desired output formatting. And that was possible only through defining the same function distance1 and not adding another function.

```
var distance1 = parseFloat(distance1.replace(",","."));
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply chain the miles and comma replacements like this

```
sanitizedDistance  = parseFloat(distance1.replace("miles","").replace(",","."))
```